# How can I see what errors Slic3r have repaird?

Tags: 3d-models, slic3r

I have an STL-file that Slic3r thinks has errors. They are not visible in the 3D view. I have had them anazlyzed in both Blender and netfabb. Both of these programs say that the model is good. I don't want to leave this to chance. Since I sell STL-files I need the STL-file perfect.

Is there any way I can find out what the problem is. I encounter this from time to time. Often I can go back into blender and find the error by analyzing the mesh. But not always. It would be very helpful to have slic3r tell me what it repaired.

Comment: "Perfect" is a qualitative term.  I might suggest that you validate your models by printing them on a couple different 3d printers.  If the result is as desired, your models pass QualityAssurance.  (and I say this as someone quite familiar with 6Sigma and similar manufacturing process methods)

Comment: @Carl-Witthoft "Perfect" is not a unique term for Quality, I´m been working as a Quality Engineer for 30 years. With 6Sigma we are working for something called Excellence, but there are errors on manufacturing.

Comment: @gunslinger Just avoid inverted walls and face walls inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slic3r uses [ADMesh](https://github.com/admesh/admesh) internally to validate and fix mesh. You could try to use ADMesh directly to see a limited information about what was changed. Note that Slic3r bundles it's own copy of ADMesh and depending on your Slic3r version and edition, the behavior of it's ADMesh might slightly differ from the standalone one. (For example Slic3r Prusa Editon patches it's own ADMesh very heavily.)

## Using ADMesh CLI:

```
$ admesh cube_bad.stl 
ADMesh version 0.98.2, Copyright (C) 1995, 1996 Anthony D. Martin
ADMesh comes with NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are welcome to
redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the file COPYING for details.
Opening cube_bad.stl
Checking exact...
Checking nearby. Tolerance= 1.000000 Iteration=1 of 2...  Fixed 0 edges.
Checking nearby. Tolerance= 1.000173 Iteration=2 of 2...  Fixed 0 edges.
Removing unconnected facets...
Filling holes...
Checking normal directions...
Checking normal values...
Calculating volume...
Verifying neighbors...

================= Results produced by ADMesh version 0.98.2 ================
Input file         : cube_bad.stl
File type          : ASCII STL file
Header             : solid cube (repaired)
============== Size ==============
Min X =  0.000000, Max X =  1.000000
Min Y =  0.000000, Max Y =  1.000000
Min Z =  0.000000, Max Z =  1.000000
========= Facet Status ========== Original ============ Final ====
Number of facets                 :    12                  12
Facets with 1 disconnected edge  :     3                   0
Facets with 2 disconnected edges :     0                   0
Facets with 3 disconnected edges :     1                   0
Total disconnected facets        :     4                   0
=== Processing Statistics ===     ===== Other Statistics =====
Number of parts       :     1        Volume   :  1.000000
Degenerate facets     :     0
Edges fixed           :     0
Facets removed        :     1
Facets added          :     1
Facets reversed       :     2
Backwards edges       :     0
Normals fixed         :     2
```

The statistics should give you some idea about what happened.

## Using ADMeshGUI:

Find ADMeshGUI at [github.com/admesh/ADMeshGUI](https://github.com/admesh/ADMeshGUI/).

Open the file and click the **REPAIR** button in bottom right. See the changes.

[image: ADMeshGUI]

Comment: Excellent, now I got a real example to test it on and worked. Excellent answer!